# SSIS project connection to AS400 acquire connection error

Tags: ssis, db2-400

I am running an SSIS package created with SSDT for Visual Studio 2015. The package has a project level connection to an AS400 DB, and my admin put a specific username and password into the environment variables on SQL Server 2016. The password is sensitive. I receive intermittent errors when running the package:

[image: Acquire connection AS400 errors]

I have the package set to restart up to 3 times on failure, and it always runs successfully the next time. Also, it does not always fail on the same container. I am the only user who uses this username/password combination, and it does not expire. The package runs every 10 minutes for 8 hours, but the errors only occur once or twice per day.

I have read numerous posts about running packages in 32 bit mode. I'm not sure if this is what I need to do. I would appreciate any help. Let me know if more detail is required.

Comment: Andrew, I can't tell if you're working on a bona fide AS400 or an ISeries. It may matter here. Case sensitivity exists for the username as well as the password. If the connection fails due to that condition, IBM's provider will resend, forcing upper case--which may explain the intermittent failures. Check with your ISeries/AS400 admin on the exact username/password combo. If you are using ODBC, examine the username/password combo there.

Comment: It is an iSeries. I will check on the password.

Comment: It is an iSeries. I will check on the password - the user name is all caps in my environmental variables in ssms. I am using the DA400 oledb connector in ssis.

Comment: Andrew, try this IBM Support page for connectivity: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1014514

Comment: If your shop will allow a linked server, try to reproduce the problem. The Support page I just posted shows that setup. Depending on what you're attempting to do beyond connecting, you may need to allow nested queries. You may also need to check for enable OLE